# Visa: "Current occupation" while doing notice?

Tags: visas, china

I've quit my job to go travel around for a long period of time. At the moment I'm still doing a few weeks of notice until I'm officially off the job.

I will already apply for my Chinese visa, but what should I enter on "current occupation", since I'm still officially working, but I won't be anymore soon and also not while I'll be traveling ofcourse.

If I already put "unemployed", will this reduce my changes of getting me a 3-month tourist visa, because they might think I'll run out of money or something? Or do I just fill in employed and my current employer and they'll just have to figure it out later?

Maybe I'm overthinking this all a bit too much, but I just want to be sure my plans won't fall apart.

Comment: You're overthinking it. You're working out your notice period. Your current occcupation is the one you're doing.

Comment: Right - just go head and put literally your current occupation.  No problem here!

Comment: @Berwyn, I went to apply and they'd sent me back. Firstly because I'm applying for 90 days and 30 is usually the max. So now I need a bunch of extra documents and a day-by-day itinerary with attractions I'll be visiting and proof of booked hotels for each city and transport between each city... Also, I needed to change my 'current occupation' to 'unemployed' and provide bank records to show I have enough money for 3 months.

Comment: @Lewis Ok. So your notice period has ended now?

Comment: @Berwyn, no not yet. My notice period ends the 24th of July. The woman told me I should choose unemployed and that I also have to bring the C4 document as proof that I've quit. I suppose it's because I apply for a period longer than the default 30 days. It's also quite a bummer that I already have to plan and book everything ahead now.

Comment: @Lewis Looks like you need more expert help now. Stick around and hopefully the visa experts will be with you shortly. Can you edit your question with the new info? It will bump it up to the top

Comment: @Lewis hi! I suggest you self-answer this question giving the answer you received at the chinese embassy, I will upvote. About the itinerary and visa questions, we have some on that already but not sure they will fit your case, don't feel afraid to ask (at worst will be closed as dupe) and feel free to ping me in chat sometime.

Comment: I suspect the reason you have been asked to put "unemployed" is because that will be your status as of the date of travel.  The application has been written on the incorrect assumption that this kind of status is permanent.  We had a question recently about someone who was planning to get married between the application and the trip, a similar problem.

Comment: @phoog, I see your point and I assume the same. In this case though, I have quit my job explicitly to be able to do this travel. The bad thing is I only get my C4 2 weeks after my notice period, which gives extra stress since I want to apply as soon as possible. (I will update my question soon and keep updating the ultimate results later on.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I went to the Chinese consulate and they asked me how I was able to go for 90 days as a tourist. I've explained that I've quit my job and am still doing notice for 2 more weeks.

**She told me to choose 'unemployed' instead of 'employed' and that I also have to provide:**

- The related C4 document;
- A statement of my leave written & signed by
  my company;
- A bank statement as proof I have enough money (50 euro X 90 days);
- A day-by-day itinerary (containing: proof of transport
  and hotels, attraction per day, ...).

I suppose the C4 document is only needed because I'll stay longer than the default 30 days for a tourism visa. (The same for the day-by-day itinerary, because last year for less than 30 days, it sufficed to only enter the names of the cities.)

And I suppose the bank statement is needed because I fill in 'unemployed'.

Comment: +1  I think people need to carefully consider how much information they volunteer on their visa applications.